# Angular 2: HTTP data not present due to race condition

Tags: angular

In my ngOnInit() method, I make a call to the data service to retrieve products data. Immediately after this call, I make a call to a local method, getProductImages(), to obtain images from the previously retrieved products but I get an error that the products: Product[] array that was the result of the getProducts() call is undefined. Apparently, the getProductImages() method is called before the the call to dataService.getProducts() completes. The code is shown below. How do I fix this.

```
export class WelcomeComponent implements OnInit {
  products: Product[];
  productImages: ProductImage[];

  constructor(private welcomeService: WelcomeService, 
    private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.dataService.getProductsDb()
    .then(products => {
      this.products = products;      
      console.log('WelcomeComponent products = ' + new Date() +
       JSON.stringify(this.products))

       this.getProductImages();
       console.log('productImages = ', JSON.stringify(this.productImages))
 })
      // .then(this.dataService.getProductImages();)
  }

  private getProductImages() {
    for(var i=0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
      this.productImages[i]._id = this.products[i]._id;
      this.productImages[i].name = this.products[i].name;
      this.productImages[i].price = this.products[i].price;
      this.productImages[i].image = this.products[i].image[0];
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Don't you have image: string in your product class? If you do, then displaying each product with its image is just <div *ngFor="product of products"> {{product.image}}</div>. Just trying to help.

Comment: Please show us the definition of Product the json that is returned to your service, and the output of the logging statements in onNgInit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your getProductImages() after you set your this.products. What's happening is they are getting called at the same time instead of one after the other. You can fix this with the following code, I believe:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.dataService.getProductsDb()
.then(products => {
  this.products = products;      
  console.log('WelcomeComponent products = ' + new Date() +
   JSON.stringify(this.products))


})
.then(
    this.getProductImages();
   console.log('productImages = ', JSON.stringify(this.productImages));
)
  // .then(this.dataService.getProductImages();)
}
```

I would look into Observables, however, which are extremely useful.
Your variables would look like:

`products: Observable<any>;`

`productImages: Observable<any>;`

Then your function could look like:

```
this.dataService.getProductsDb()
.map(response => response.json())
.subscribe(response => {
  this.products = response;
},
  error => console.log(error),
  () => {
    this.getProductImages();
    console.log('productImages = ', JSON.stringify(this.productImages));
  });
```

You can read more at https://github.com/reactivex/rxjs and http://reactivex.io/